# comparision strings from struct in if statement

Tags: c++, arrays, string, struct

I wrote a c++ code and used struct, I want to compare two string in struct type.but error occures:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define NumOfStudents 2
#define NumOfCourses 3

struct Student{
  int stdnum, FieldCode, age;
  double average, marks, res[NumOfCourses];
  char Fname[20], Lname[20], cmp[20];
};


int main(){
  struct Student students[NumOfStudents];
  int i, j;
  //  char cmp[20];

  cout << "\t    **********************************************************************\n";
  cout << "\t    *++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*\n";
  cout << "\t    *+  FIRST-NAME || LAST-NAME || STUDENT-NUMBER || FIELD-CODE || AGE  +*\n";
  cout << "\t    *++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*\n";
  cout << "\t    **********************************************************************\n";

  for(i=0; i<NumOfStudents; i++){
    cout << "STUDENT #" << i+1 << ": ";
    cin >> students[i].Fname >> students[i].Lname >> students[i].stdnum >> students[i].FieldCode >> students[i].age;
  }

  cout << "what student do you want?[Enter family]\n";
  cin >> students[j].cmp;

  for(i=0; i<NumOfStudents; i++){
    if(students[j].cmp == students[j].Lname){    //The error occurs here
      for(j=0; j<NumOfCourses; j++){
    cout << "\nCOURCE #" << j+1 << ": ";
    cin >> students[j].marks;
      }
    }
    else
      cout << "The Student with name " << students[j].cmp << " doesn't exist!!!";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In the code I commented place the error occurred...

thank you

Comment: Save yourself a lot of trouble and use `std::string` instead of `char` arrays.

Comment: I don't know how to change code..thank you if help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course this comparison

```
if(students[j].cmp == students[j].stdnum){
```

is invalid because data member cmp has type `char[20]` and stdnum has type `int`. It is not clear what you are going to compare.

EDIT: I see you updated your post and wrote

```
if(students[j].cmp == students[j].Lname){
```

However this statement is also invalid because arrays have no the comparison operator. In this condition the both arrays are converted to pointers to their first elements and the pointers are compared. So the condition will be equal always to false. Instead you have to use strandard C function strcmp

```
if( std::strcmp( students[j].cmp, students[j].Lname ) == 0 ){
```

It would be simpler if you would use std::string instead of character arrays. You need to include header `<string>`

In this case the structure will look the following way

```
struct Student{
  int stdnum, FieldCode, age;
  double average, marks, res[NumOfCourses];
  string Fname, Lname, cmp;
};
```

and you could use the comparison operator

```
if( students[j].cmp == students[j].Lname ){
```

Comment: Why negative? I corrected it before answering you friend...see the post again

Comment: @juanchopanza Obviously we have been seeing different versions of the question.

Comment: ok there is a problem...my for statement[after that comparision] doent work..do you know why? thank you

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow as knowing more and better, can you add std::string model? and let me know about it? thank you.

Comment: @MortezaLSC See my uodated post.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you.

```
if(strcmp(students[i].cmp, students[i].Lname) == 0)
```

Comment: my for statement[after that comparision] doent work..do you know why?

Comment: You were trying to use `j` before the inner loop (where you initialize it).

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about using `char` string, you should use `strcmp` function to compare them.
(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a variable `j` which has no value assigned to it. Because of that, you are accessing an unknown member in the array, probably something off the array's boundaries (an index larger than `NumOfStudents`).

I think you want `if(students[i].cmp == students[i].stdnum){` instead of `if(students[j].cmp == students[j].stdnum){`, still, it should be noted that you are comparing two `char` arrays, which does not have your intended effect of comparing the two strings. It will probably compare the position of the arrays in the memory(will always evaluate to `false`). Instead use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/), and use commands from the `<cstring>` library when dealing with  cstrings (char arrays).

Or just save yourself the trouble and use the [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/?kw=string) class, which overloads the = operator and lets you compare two strings using `=`.